# Excel VBA How to Remove all the Duplicate rows based on column C

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new in Excel vba, What i am trying to do here is, 
Remove all the duplicate rows based on values in Column C. so whenever column c have duplicate values it will remove the entire row. So far i have this

```
Sub RemoveDupe()
Dim rCell As Range 
Dim rRange As Range 
Dim lCount As Long 

Set rRange = Range("C1", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 
lCount = rRange.Rows.Count 

For lCount = lCount To 1 Step -1 
    With rRange.Cells(lCount, 1) 
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then 
            .EntireRow.Delete 
        End If 
    End With 
Next lCount 
End Sub
```

but here it's leving the first value, i want to remove that one too. Only rows will be remaining whom did'nt have any duplicates or unique ones.
any help?

Comment: Why not use Remove Duplicates from the Data menu? I don't think it's good practice to use the same variable for two different things.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to remove ALL rows that contained duplicate data or just until you only have no duplicates? Your first and last paragraph seem to be conflicting.

Comment: @BerticusMaximus - indeed so, "did'nt have any duplicates" OR "unique"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCheck As Range
    Dim rDel As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    For Each rCheck In ws.Range("C1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Columns("C"), rCheck.Value) > 1 Then
            If Not rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, rCheck)
            Else
                Set rDel = rCheck
            End If
        End If
    Next rCheck

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A1:D10").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3), Header:=xlYes
```

will remove all rows in the selected range, with duplicate values in the third column

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way; it first colors the duplicate cells and then deletes the rows for each colored cell.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell

    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```